# Alternative definition of Kolmogorov complexity

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

In Kikuchi's paper [Kolmogorov complexity and the second incompleteness theorem](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0912-3.pdf) the Kolmogorov Complexity (KC) of $x$ is defined as

$$ K(x) = \mu e (\varphi_e(0) \simeq x) \, . $$

This seems to give exponentially larger outcomes then the more common (rough) definition of $K(x)$ as "the length of the smallest computer program running on some fixed universal TM that returns $x$". How does Kikuchi's definition match up with the usual KC definition? Is this a common alternative? Does any major result in KC change/not work under this new definition, or can we just move everything by an exponent and rely on its monotonicity?

Comment: Can you explain the notation in the definition? I think it's "smallest $e$ such that the $e$th program (in some enumeration) outputs $x$ on input $0$."

Comment: @usul That's how I read it as well, with the extra condition that this $e$th program should terminate, of course. Kikuchi doesn't say any more about it.

Comment: It does seem to me that Kikuchi is using an exponentiated version of regular Kolmogorov complexity. For example, he says things like "we say a number $x$ is random if $x \le K(x)$", which makes sense if we think of an encoding of a number as needing about $\log_2 n$ bits. I have not seen this version in other places, but since exponentiation is monotonic, I don't see how it would change things much.

Comment: Can you specify which “usual theorems” you have in mind? This would make the question more precise and concrete.

Comment: @user76284 I don't know that much about the general theory of KC, so my question is open: does any major result in KC change/not work under this new definition? One thing that is quite different is that no two strings can have the same complexity under Kikuchi's definition. But I'm not sure whether this impacts anything significant. Like Artemy says exponentiation is monotonic, so it seems we're all good. But the definition is quite unusual, hence maybe someone with more experience in KC can tell whether it really boils down to the same thing or not (but with everything exponentiated).

Comment: If you don’t get a response here, it might be worth asking on the [Theoretical CS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Kikuchi mentions Odifreddi's Classical Recursion Theory (North-Holland, 1989) as the source of that particular definition, and that's also the earliest occurrence I know of. Another paper using the same definition, also citing Odifreddi's book, is P. Raatikainen's On interpreting Chaitin's incompleteness theorem (JPL 27:569-586, 1998).

Comment: @user103227 Where does Kikuchi mention that?

Comment: Last paragraph of the introduction: "we [...] define Kolmogorov complexity following Odifreddi".

Comment: @user103227 Is that In Odifreddi volume I or II? Does he motivate the definition? Thanks, btw for your help :). I'll also try shooting Raatikainen an email.

Comment: @Jori It's in volume I. I don't have a physical copy available, but in the [pdf](http://www.piergiorgioodifreddi.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/CRT1.pdf) available on Odifreddi's website, the definition is on page 151.